# Do the darker impulses of society ever appear in the SW universe materials?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I know that Star Wars is generally kept PG, or at least PG-13 in some cases, but it got me to wondering. I'm pretty familiar with a significant chunk of the Legends continuity, yet I can't remember any depictions of the... darker impulses of society.

**Are there any examples in Legends continuity of rape, incest, or violent (serial killer) crime?**

The closest thing I could find to a serial killer was the tale of Jedi [**Vydel Dir'Nul**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vydel_Dir'Nul). Even the Sith, who are generally depicted as the most evil killers in the universe, are never depicted as doing the really bad stuff - they just kill, or maybe torture in a PG fashion.

Comment: Odd how no one mentions the torture of Leia in ANH.

Comment: Your list of 3 immediatley reminds one of "[Arson, Murder, and Jaywalking](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ArsonMurderAndJaywalking)". Enjoy TVTroping, all'ya'll

Comment: @DVK - lol, if you mean the incest part, that was a direct nod to Luke & Leia kissing in ESB.

Comment: “maybe torture in a PG fashion” — just your regular, healthy, good old American-style torture.

Comment: Blowing up Alderaan doesn't qualify as a darker impulse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Within the main canon

**No. Absolutely not.** Although murder is depicted in considerable detail (and infanticide is strongly hinted at) there are no rapes, serial murders or incidents of incest. Ultimately this is a series of film and TV shows that are aimed at children younger adults and considerable effort has been expended in keeping it, to a large extent, family-friendly.

There are some off-camera hints about the keeping of sex-slaves (twiileks, especially) but minimial explicit info.

### Within the EU

**Rape - Yes, a reasonable number of references but no vivid depictions**

- > Weequay didn’t all look the same. She knew this one. He had chased her
  >   across a barq field. **He was a rapist and a murderer,** not that the
  >   descriptions set him apart from any other of Hokan’s thugs. She
  >   reached for her lightsaber. - <sub><sup>SW: Republic Commando</sup></sub>
- http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ilir_Post
- http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Warlug

---

**Incest,** [not so much](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ccosUUPPvk)

---

**Serial Murder**

Loads and loads. Heck, Vader spent the intervening 20 years tracking down and killing dozens of remaining Jedi.

Comment: Seeing as Vader was operating under the orders of the Emperor, his systematic killing of the Jedi wasn't a case of violent serial killer *crime*.

Comment: @Null - The Emperor arranges for a wide variety of murders as well as committing numerous murders of his own.

Comment: Incest - think again: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEV7pKkTylw

Comment: In *Lords of the Sith*, it's heavily implied that the Imperials would enslave and rape Twilek women. I believe the novel is part of the new main canon.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of any example of incest or a serial killer (in the criminal sense) in Legends.

The *Legacy of the Force* series includes a reference to an instance in which Boba Fett's wife [Sintas Vel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sintas_Vel) was raped by Fett's superior officer, the Journeyman Protector [Lenovar](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lenovar). Fett killed him for it.

A [search for "rape" on Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Search?search=rape&go=&fulltext=Search) reveals some other references to rapes (and attempted rapes) in more obscure sources:

- The attempted rape of [Rasha Bex](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rasha_Bex) by an Imperial officer named [Tregor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tregor).

  [image]
- The gang rape of [Liane Trevval](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Liane_Trevval) by six men early in her life.
- The attempted rape of [Yarna d'al' Gargan](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yarna_d%27al%27_Gargan) by the Gamorrean [Warlug](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Warlug) and the human [Tornik](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tornik).
- The attempted rape of [Pamr](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Pamr) by [Ilir Post](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ilir_Post).
- The attempted rape of an [unidentified Jabiimi prisoner](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Unidentified_Jabiimi_prisoner) by Imperial Lieutenant [Clynn](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Clynn).

Comment: I assumed that rape was one of the unpleasant things that happened to Shmi Skywalker when she was abducted by Sand People.

Comment: @WadCheber That's a distinct possibility. It's not explicitly stated that she was, though, so I can't really say it was "depicted".

Comment: @WadCheber - There's no evidence of that whatsoever. The canon just says that she was made to feel pain.

Comment: Interesting. I'm a big fan of The Fett, yet I never knew about that happening to Sintas.

Comment: @Omegacron You're a fan of Fett?! I had no idea!

Comment: @Null - lol yep, so much so that I just ordered the Blood Ties TPB from Amazon. A gap in my Fett knowledge just will not stand.

Comment: I always assumed that Anakin was conceived through rape Shmi being a slave and all and it would make more sense then him being conceived of the force. But that's just a theory.

Answer (score 0):

Palpatine killed his entire family if that's not one of the "Darker Impuses" I don't know what is and before you say anything yes I know Palpatine was a Sith but this happened before he even knew the Sith existed and and it was pretty much unprovoked really it was just a really extreme temper tantrum so I think it counts.